# he thought to be working for the Russian government

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, indian-english, learning

I have a doubt in "to be working". And can I use "to be worked" instead of "to be working"?
I'd like to know the exact difference in meaning between them?
Please help me...

Here's the example sentence:

> Hackers **thought to be working** for the Russian government recently penetrated the White House’s unclassified computer networks.

Comment: Where did you find it? Any reference? *he was thought to be...* seems correct.

Comment: Yes, Aravind, please provide a full sentence. You could strip it of all the sensitive information, we need only a generic guide to understand the role of the construction you're uncertain about.

Comment: "Hackers thought to be working for the Russian government recently penetrated the White House’s unclassified computer networks."This is the full sentence....

Comment: In this example, "Crackers" is the correct term, not "Hackers".

Answer (score 2):

*Hackers **thought to be working for the Russian government** recently penetrated the White House’s unclassified computer networks.*

*Hackers, **thought to be working for the Russian government**, recently penetrated the White House’s unclassified computer networks.*

Both of these are possible. The clauses in bold can be understood as reduced forms of "who are thought to be working for the Russian government". The first is a defining clause, the second a non-defining clause.

*Hackers **thought to be worked for the Russian government** recently penetrated the White House’s unclassified computer networks.* This is not possible. In this context, 'work' is intransitive, and can have no passive form.

Comment: +1, nice answer. However the OP would like to know if *thought to be worked* is valid English.

Comment: @Lucian Sava : It might be can used as 'to be worked' because it is Russia.

Comment: @Lucian, Sure, "*thought to be worked*" can certainly be grammatical English: "*The archeologists discovered several artifacts. The smooth, round stones are **thought to be worked**, but since they were found on a dried riverbed, more analysis is needed for a conclusive determination*". Or, "*The stones, **thought to be worked**, were found on the steppes of Tunisia*", or whatever.

Comment: @ Lucian Save (first comment). Good point. I have added a note on this to my answer.